# Windows kernel development devicehandle Invalid Handle Value

Tags: driver, ioctl, windows-kernel

So I'm currently following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaIMgJz05wI&t=2s on kernel development. When I try to click on "open device" in my usermode program the devicehandle returns a Invalid handle value although I correctly mapped my driver and my device link is the same.

Usermode Code:

```
HANDLE devicehandle = NULL;

void CKMDFDriverTut1userDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    devicehandle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\myDeviceLink123", GENERIC_ALL, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM, 0);
    if (devicehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MessageBox(L"not valid value", 0, 0);
        return;
    }
    //do your ting if valid
    MessageBox(L"valid value", 0, 0);
}
```

KernelMode:

```
DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;

UNICODE_STRING DeviceName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\myDevice123");
UNICODE_STRING SymLinkName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\\myDeviceLink123");

PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject = NULL;

VOID Unload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) 
{
    IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&SymLinkName);
    IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
    KdPrint(("Driver Unload \r\n"));
}

NTSTATUS DispatchPassThru(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION irpsp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    switch (irpsp->MajorFunction)
    {
    case IRP_MJ_CREATE:
        KdPrint(("create request \r\n"));
        break;
    case IRP_MJ_CLOSE:
        KdPrint(("close resuest \r\n"));
        break;
    case IRP_MJ_READ:
        KdPrint(("read request \r\n"));
        break;
    case IRP_MJ_WRITE:
        KdPrint(("write resuest \r\n"));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
)
{

    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    int i;
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;

    status = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, 0, &DeviceName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &DeviceObject);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        KdPrint(("Creating device failed \r\n"));
        return status;
    }

    status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&SymLinkName, &DeviceName);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        KdPrint(("creating symbolic link failed \r\n"));
        IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
        return status;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION; i++) {
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = DispatchPassThru;
    }

    //DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ] = DispatchCustom;
    //DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_WRITE] = DispatchCustom1;

    KdPrint(("Driver load \r\n"));

    return status;
}
```

The expected output is that when I click Button1 a Message Box appears and says "valid value" but instead a Message Box appears saying "not valid value" which means my device handle is wrong. I would greatly appreciate help, Thanks.

[The device was successfully created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gob7l.png)

Comment: you forget `DeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;`. and for what you create symbolic link to your device ?

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it :D

Comment: if you call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` after `CreateFile` fail or better direct call `NtOpenFile/NtCreateFile` - you got error `STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE` which will be hint, why. and main - you not need create any symbolic link, even for `CreateFile` call. use  \\\\?\\globalroot\\Device\\myDevice123 path

Comment: Oh I did not know that. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

As first step debugging this type of issue, my suggestion is to verify and confirm your device was successfully created as an object and visible in the namespace.  One way to do so is using the Microsoft's tool: WinObj. This tool available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj

Comment: The device was successfully created and is visible in WinObj

Comment: In your usermode code, please obtain the extended error information after your codes receive INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE from calling CreateFile().  Use GetLastError() to obtain the extended error information which will shed some lights on your issue.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help. RbMm pointed out what I forgot and I fixed it :D

Answer (score 0):

When you access a device in the \\.\ Area, it means access by DosDevice name. Therefore, a symbolic link must be created in the DosDevice area on the driver side.

The following link will help you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/introduction-to-ms-dos-device-names

Comment: I thought I created a symbolic link here: status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&SymLinkName, &DeviceName );

Comment: WinObj can also show you the symbolic links that exist.

Comment: @DaRealHeroofHell Try setting symbolicklink name to the \DosDevices\ area.

Comment: @reinhard v.z Thank you so much for your help. RbMm pointed out what I forgot and I fixed it :D